# Extract average values of multiple columns via ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Grade model from which I need to pull the averages of two columns - accuracy and time. I’m using the following query to get both values together instead of querying the model twice.

```
Grade.where(student_id: 25).pluck('avg(accuracy), avg(time)')
```

I get two values alright, but they are in the following format which I do not understand:

```
[[#<BigDecimal:7f9c5a890410,’8.0’,9(18)>, #<BigDecimal:7f9c5a8903c0,’10.0’,9(18)>]]
```

How do I extract only the values that I need from this? i.e. avg_accuracy = 8.0 and avg_time = 10.0

I'm new to Ruby, Rails, ActiveRecord. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
grades = Grade.where(student_id: 25, class_id: 123).pluck('avg(accuracy), avg(time)').first
```

Should get

```
[#<BigDecimal:7f9c5a890410,’8.0’,9(18)>, #<BigDecimal:7f9c5a8903c0,’10.0’,9(18)>]
```

and now convert them to simple floats.

```
grades.map!(&:to_f)
```

should get

```
[8.0, 10.0]
```

Comment: Tried that. But when I use find_by with pluck, it returns the following error.

    NoMethodError: undefined method `pluck' for #<Grade:0x007f9c596689e0>

Also, what if I have to query by not just student_id, but also class_id?

Comment: You're right. I updated my answer. If you have more than one condition you can pass an hash with multiple key/value to where. `Grade.where(student_id: 123, class_id: 234)`

Comment: Thank you, that worked! :)

Incidentally, the result that I get from the query is in the form of an array within an array, like so [[ #<...>, #<...> ]]
So I did grades[0].map!(&:to_f). Not sure if this is a good practice, but it worked.

Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you called `.first` at the end of the query? Watch the end of my first snippet

Comment: No, I had not. That solves the problem. Thanks for pointing it out.